# Amazon S3: Uncaught Error: Class 'S3Client' not found

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a `.zip` file to the Amazon S3 service but I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught  Error: Class 'S3Client' not found in /class/database.class.php:411

This is the basis of the code.  I have the `exit()` from trying to debug.  The `class_exists` function specifis that the S3Client exists and echo's "Class!!!" to the page.
I added an echo statement in the amazon autoload file and it echo's that so it is finding the autoload files.

Why can't PHP find the class when trying to call it?

**My Amazon Class**

```php
    require_once( $path["full"].'/assets/vendor/amazon-s3/aws-autoloader.php' );
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    class amazons3 {
        // For future use to build some functions to help.
    }
```

**My-Autoload**

```php
     //Misc Functions Above    
      include('/path/to/amazon-s3.class.php')
    //Misc Functions Below
```

**Inside Back-up Database Function**

```php
     include('/path/to/my/my-autoload.class.php');
     if(class_exists('Aws\S3\S3Client')) {
        echo "CLASS!!!";
        /* Line 411 */ $s3 = new S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'us-west-2'
        ]);
                        
    }
    else {
        echo "No Class";
    }
    exit(0);
                            
    try {
        $s3->putObject([
            'Bucket' => $data["domain"],
            'Key'    => 'my-object',
            'Body'   => fopen($zipName, 'r'),
            'ACL'    => 'public-read',
        ]);
    } catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
    }
```

**Update**
I am not using composer; I downloaded the package and uploaded it to my server.

I've still had no luck with getting this to recognize the S3Client class.  I added an echo to the top of the S3Client.php right above the class that is in the amazon package to see if it is included and it is and echoed out the string on my page, so from everything I know, all Amazon class files are included.

**Update 2**
I added the include files to the include of the Amazon autoloader.

Comment: I assume you are using `composer`for the dependency if so make sure to add the `autoload.php`file on your php file.

Comment: You assume wrong.  I downloaded the zip and uploaded the files.  My host doesn't have composer installed.  The files are included in my file.

Comment: Instead of someone voting my question down at least tell me why you voted it down so I can improve me question.

Comment: Why not just use a built in linux tool like wget to download the composer phar file? Messing around with zip files is a waste of time.

Comment: Also, from the code you uploaded there is not sign of you including a file with the S3Client class.

Comment: @x43  I have updated my code to show the "paths" and minimum code required to include the files.  As far as using wget to get the phar file, how does that work once you get the composer phar file and not have composer?

Comment: Once you download the "phar" file, run `alias composer="php composer.phar"` and you can run composer commands in that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `class_exists` call, you specify the fully-qualified class name (with its namespace):

```
     if(class_exists('Aws\S3\S3Client')) {
        echo "CLASS!!!";
    }
```

But when you try to instantiate it, you use just the class name:

```
        /* Line 411 */ $s3 = new S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'us-west-2'
        ]);
```

Note that the error message doesn't include the namespace `Aws\S3`, because PHP doesn't know that `S3Client` should actually mean `Aws\S3\S3Client`.

If you instantiate the class with its fully-qualified name it will work:

```
        /* Line 411 */ $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'us-west-2'
        ]);
```

For the name `S3Client` to expand to `Aws\S3\S3Client`, your code needs to either a) be inside the `Aws\S3` namespace; or b) have an appropriate `use` statement at the top of the file.

The important thing to remember is that `namespace` and `use` statements *only affect the current file*, they can't be loaded via a `require`/`include`.

So this will also work:

```
/* top of file */
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
// ...
        /* Line 411 */ $s3 = new S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'us-west-2'
        ]);
```

The name you use for the class can be different in every file, with `use ... as`, so you can also do this:

```
/* top of file */
use Aws\S3\S3Client as AmazonS3;
use Something\Else as S3Client;
// ...
        /* Line 411 */ $s3 = new AmazonS3([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'us-west-2'
        ]);
```

To see what PHP resolves a bare class name to in a particular file, you can use the magic `::class` suffix, which just expands the name according to current `namespace` and `use` rules (even if there isn't actually a class with that name):

```
if ( class_exists(S3Client::class) ) {
    echo 'Class exists: ' . S3Client::class;
}
else {
    echo 'Class does not exist: ' . S3Client::class;
}
```

This is almost always what you want to do when you want a fully-qualified class name in a string.

Comment: That's the best explanation so far.  I've had namespaces in by using PHPMailer but I declared the class to a variable right after in the same file so that's I could access it when I included it.  I will give this a shot. :)